# Enable Interval in Node vm2 module

Tags: node.js, module, virtual-machine

I stumbled around an issue with vm2 module, as it by default does not allow timeouts and intervals.

```
setInterval(function () {
  doStuff();
}, 1000);
console.log('done')
```

The interval is ignored, and the program immediately logs `done`.
I read all the documentation, and browsed a lot, but couldn't find a way to turn them on. Is it even possible?

**EDIT**: I didn't even realize, that my problem is actually not the vm module itself, but the fact, that I am not calling the script directly, but using a separate module. Workaround for this would be tracking all the intervals and timeouts before returning the result for the module, as, in my case, I don't have too much control on user input.

Comment: Just  a guess, but use `vm.createContext()` and give it an object that has `setInterval()` on it as a property.  Then, use that context object with `wm.runInContext()` and that context object will be the global object in your vm, thus making `setInterval()` available.

Comment: The problem is that it exists on the instance, and even if you pass it as a global object, it still doesn't execute.